# reading text data into R while maintaining column structure

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a tab-delimited file that contains 3 columns (BookID,BookName,BookReview);
Sample data;

```
0001    Hannibal    This was a great book that is awesome.....etc.......
```

I am trying to do something text mining on the book reviews, but I need to maintain the structure of the data set so that I can mine each book id at a time, and not mix all the reviews together. When I try to read this into R, I get an error and lose most of the records

I am trying;

```
dat <- read.table(~/my_text.txt,sep='\t')
```

How can I read this into R without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, assuming you have fixed widths.

```
   read.fwf("file path to the text file", widths = 
                                          c(width of variable 1,
                                            width of variable 2,
                                            width of variable 3
                                           )
             )
```

Example:

```
read.fwf("C:/Users/Infinite Flash/Downloads/Datasets/APR05FRL.TXT", widths = c(10,6,12))
```

For more information and specifics, I suggest looking at this link:

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Data_input_and_output/Loading_data_from_a_file/

If this none of this is helpful, please explain why.

Comment: The 3rd column will never be fixed width, it is a free flow text column (user review)